# sqlite3 and cursor.description

Tags: python, sqlite, python-db-api

When using the sqlite3 module in python, all elements of cursor.description except the column names are set to None, so this tuple cannot be used to find the column types for a query result (unlike other DB-API compliant modules). Is the only way to get the types of the columns to use `pragma table_info(table_name).fetchall()` to get a description of the table, store it in memory, and then match the column names from cursor.description to that overall table description?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not the only way. Alternatively, you can also fetch one row, iterate over it, and inspect the individual column Python objects and types. Unless the value is None (in which case the SQL field is NULL), this should give you a fairly precise indication what the database column type was.

sqlite3 only uses `sqlite3_column_decltype` and `sqlite3_column_type` in one place, each, and neither are accessible to the Python application - so their is no "direct" way that you may have been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this in Python, but you could try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table';
```

which contains the DDL CREATE statement used to create the table. By parsing the DDL you can get the column type info, such as it is. Remember that SQLITE is rather vague and unrestrictive when it comes to column data types.